# Sending/Receiving Faxes in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, fax

I need to send/receive faxes through my web application, and I am not sure where to begin.

Basically, a client clicks a button to send a fax, and records in the database under the client's name when a fax is received.

Preferably through an API from a service based fax company... I will be hosting this application on a dedicated server, I don't think they allow using their modems.

I am using .NET and VB, any ideas?

EDIT: I did some search on Google, http://www.efaxdeveloper.com/ is the closest thing I found. I am not sure how to implement it yet. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: How do you plan on sending and receiving the faxes? Through a modem on the server? A connected fax machine? Someone else's API?

Comment: Preferably someone else's API.. I will be hosting this web application from a dedicated server.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I get so frustrated with faxes coming in and then being scanned or photocopied at work.  The end result is never readable, this the sort of thing I've wanted to implement for a paperless-office solution to that problem.

Comment: eFaxDeveloper has a free trial.. see if you can get something working using their SDK.  If so, then problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried eFaxDeveloper, and works exactly like how I've described.

Answer (score 3):

You might try to P/Invoke to winfax.dll.  Someone has asked the same [question on another forum](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=97317).

Here's an [example](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1476985.php) using C# - You asked for a solution using VB but the process is virtually identical.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling your own solution may not be the best thing. If you do a ton of faxing you might want to check out something like [rightfax](http://www.captaris.com/rightfax/). We rolled out a web interface for our clients, but pass the work off to the rightfax server. We like it because it can manage the retries and errors, you know stuff you may not want to have to deal with on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

We did some testing with [Premiere Global](http://www.premiereglobal.com/fax-document-delivery/everyday-faxing/) a while ago. They have an SMTP based API for sending faxes. In the end we decided to stick with our modem-based solution, but the Premiere stuff was pretty easy to get up and running as I recall.